# unfortunately, myapp has stopped when using if clause in OnClick event

Tags: java, if-statement, clause

I've a problem when created my first project that error unfortunately, myapp has stopped. Here is code error:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button btnLogin;
EditText txtUsername;
EditText txtPassword;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnLogin=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){         
            public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (txtUsername.getText().toString().equals(txtPassword.getText().toString()))
            {
                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }                   
        }           
    });       


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

But if i don't use "If clause" only Toasted.maketext....show() it ok. I think maybe wrong in " If clause" but i don't know.

Comment: are you getting the txtUsername view somewhere in your code? If so, can you paste the complete class plus xml layout?

Answer (score 1):

1. Your code doesn't initialize `txtUsername` variable. You need to do that, or else you will get a `NullPointerException`.
2. You are using `txtUsername` variable in a (anonymous) inner class. In order to do that, the variable has to be a final one.